# Problema ao Trocar Imagem com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá!
Fiz  uma função usando Javascript para trocar uma imagem por outra.
A ideia é que exista uma imagem principal, essa imagem principal deve ser trocada quando clicarem nas imagens secundárias abaixo dela, e que a imagem principal vire a imagem que foi clicada. 
Para não fazer uma função para cada imagem, tentei fazer uma função só com switch case, em que o DOM retorna o SRC das imagens, em variáveis diferentes e que em cada case a imagem principal pegue o valor da secundária. 
Porém quando clico nas imagens, nada acontece e o console retorna a seguinte mensagem:

---

> trocaImagem.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
>       at trocaImagem (trocaImagem.js:3)
>       at HTMLImageElement.onclick (index.html:202)

---

Por favor, podem me ajudar?

Seguem os códigos JS e HTML

```js
function trocaImagem(){

    var imagemPrincipal = document.getElementById("imagem_principal").src 
    var imagem_certificado01 = document.getElementById("imagem_certificado01").src
    var imagem_certificado02 = document.getElementById("imagem_certificado02").src
    var imagem_certificado03 = document.getElementById("iamgem_certificado03").src
    var imagem_certificado04 = document.getElementById("imagem_certificado04").src

    var pegaImagem = [imagem_certificado01, imagem_certificado02, imagem_certificado03, imagem_certificado04]

    switch (pegaImagem){

        case 01:
            imagemPrincipal = imagem_certificado01
            break;
        case 02:
            imagemPrincipal = imagem_certificado02
            break;
        case 03:
            imagemPrincipal = imagem_certificado03
            break;
        case 04:
            imagemPrincipal = imagem_certificado04
            break;

    }
}
```

```html
<!--------------------------------------SEÇÃO DE DIPLOMAS E CERTIFICADOS--------------------------------------------->

  <section class="jumbotron bg-transparent">
    <h1 data-aos="fade-up" class="display-4">Diplomas e Certificados</h1>
    <hr class="my-4">


    <section class="certificado_principal">

      <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 50rem;">
        <img src="img/diploma01.jpg" class=" imagem_certificado_principal border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </section>

      <section class= "diplomas ">

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class=" border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="img/diploma01.jpg" onclick="trocaImagem()" class=" imagem_certificado01 border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="  border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="img/certificadoteste.jpg" onclick="trocaImagem()" class="imagem_certificado02 border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="  border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="img/certificadoteste4.png" onclick="trocaImagem()" class=" imagem_certificado03 border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class=" imagem05 border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="img/diplomatestecaelum.jfif" onclick="trocaImagem()" class=" imagem_certificado04 border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
       </section>     


<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Não há elementos com os id's nas linhas onde vc tenta pegar os .src. Por exemplo, aqui: `var imagemPrincipal = document.getElementById("imagem_principal").src`..não há nenhum elemento com o id `imagem_principal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bruno, o problema é que no código JavaScript você utiliza o método `document.getElementById()`, passando para ele id de elementos HTML, porém no código HTML você sequer usar o seletor *id*. Sem contar que há um erro de ortografia dentro do seu código JS, você escreve "*iamgem_certificado03*" em vez de "*imagem_certificado03*"

Portanto, seu código HTML deve usar uma *id* para a imagem principal, e não uma *class*. O mesmo acontece com as outras imagens. Dessa forma, seu código deve ficar assim:

```js
function trocaImagem(elemento){
    var imagemPrincipal = document.getElementById("imagem_principal")
    if(elemento.id != 'imagem_principal')
        [imagemPrincipal.src, elemento.src] = [elemento.src, imagemPrincipal.src]
}
```

```html
  <section class="jumbotron bg-transparent">
    <h1 data-aos="fade-up" class="display-4">Diplomas e Certificados</h1>
    <hr class="my-4">


    <section class="certificado_principal">

      <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 50rem;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200?text=principal" id="imagem_principal" class=" imagem_certificado_principal border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </section>

      <section class= "diplomas ">

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class=" border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=certificado01" onclick="trocaImagem(this)" id="imagem_certificado01" class="  border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="  border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=certificado02" onclick="trocaImagem(this)" id="imagem_certificado02" class=" border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class="  border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=certificado03" onclick="trocaImagem(this)" id="imagem_certificado03" class="  border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div ata-aos="fade-up" class=" imagem05 border border-dark card text-center m-3  p-3 bg-secondary text-white" style="width: 25rem;">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200?text=certificado04" onclick="trocaImagem(this)"  id="imagem_certificado04" class="  border border-warning card-img-top  w-100 text-center  imagem_diploma" alt="Imagem de Bootstrap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Diploma de Ensino Superior - Tecnologia em Análise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas - UniÍtalo 2019</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações que o Senhor passou, mas o mesmo erro continua aparecendo:  Não entendo, a linha 3 é a que chama o src da imagem principal, só que parece que está vindo null.

Comment: Você copiou o código que coloquei aqui? Aqui funciona normalmente...

Comment: Desculpa, tinha um erro no código JS que esqueci de consertar, mas tá certo agora, se copiar agora verá que funciona normalmente.

Comment: Opa! Então, agora o código não retorna nenhum erro e o ok do console.log aparece, só que a imagem em si não troca, ela continua a mesma.

Comment: Eu resolvi o problema que vc descreveu na pergunta, porém, vejo que, além do problema de sintaxe, seu código contém um erro de lógica. Portanto, eu refiz o código HTML e a função JavaScript, que agora faz exatamente o que você quer. Nota: coloquei o `src` um link que pega uma imagem gerada. É bom para ilustrar, mas troque e adapte aos seus arquivos.

Comment: @BrunoEduardoRosselli, editei o código mais uma vez, execute-o e veja se faz o que vc quer.